# OpenSQLConnection error

Tags: warning-messages, databaselink, sql, databases

I used to be able to connect to a SQL Server database.  I haven't run this program for a few months.  I tried it today and it failed, so I went back to try OpenSQLConnection[] and got the following error:

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in server:1433/<>database.
```

I began my program with:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
Needs["JLink`"];
```

I tried to connect to my database anyway, but that returned:

```
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC[Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS),
server:1433/ <> database],  "Catalog" -> TOA_DW,
Description -> The reinsurance data warehouse.  Connection
created on September 5, 2013., Location->
C:\Users\mkaplan\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\
DatabaseResources\warehouse.m, Name -> warehouse, 
Password ->  , Properties -> {}, 
ReadOnly -> False, RelativePath -> False, Timeout -> Automatic,
TransactionIsolationLevel -> ReadUncommitted, 
UseConnectionPool -> False, Username -> , Version -> 2.]
```

When I ran SQLConnections[] I got nothing.

Then I tried to connect to the demo database.  Got the same initial error when I executed OpenSQLConnection[]. I manually tried to connect to demo through the UI and got a bunch more of the same "StringJoin" errors.  However when I ran SQLConnections[] I did get:

```
{SQLConnection["demo", 1, Open, TransactionIsolationLevel -> ReadCommitted]}
```

Which I think means that it connected.

There **have** been some changes to permissions that were put into place since the last time I ran this successfully.  However OpenSQLConnections[] isn't specifying anything, so I wonder why I got that initial "StringJoin" error.  Also, I **can** connect to my database using the SQL Management Studio.

Can anyone suggest where to start looking for the problem?

Comment: What that error message means is that is that `database` has not been defined. It should be a string, right now it's not.

Comment: @Pickett - I thought that by entering OpenSQLConnection without any parameters I could enter the database through the resultant UI. Then I would save it as a connection along with the database server, and various other parameters.  What am I missing?

Comment: You haven't shared the code that defines `database` so I can't tell you what's wrong, but for some reason it's not a string and so `StringJoin` throws that error.

Comment: @Pickett - I haven't defined "database" anywhere.  I assume that you're referring to a constant called "database" that I should have assigned a value to?  I'm not using anything called database.  Am I misunderstanding you?  Also, the code that worked a few months ago is untouched and doesn't work now.  I must be misunderstanding.

Comment: Oh sorry, WITHOUT any parameters... I thought that was your code. I've never used the GUI so I'm afraid I cannot help.

Comment: @Pickett - Thanks anyway, I appreciate that you made the effort to try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was solved by Wolfram support.  Apparently there was some corruption in one or more Mathematica files.  We solved the problem by deleting the following folders (Windows 7, 64 bit):

C:\ProgramData\Mathematica

C:\Users\mkaplan\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica

When I then ran Mathematica, it recreated these folders and the error went away.

Comment: This solved my issue as well.  I did have to reactivate when I started the program after deleting the directories so make sure you have your activation key handy.