# OpenSQLConnection fails - due to some Java problem?

Tags: java, databaselink, sql

After upgrading to 12.3, I can no longer connect to an MS SQL Server using OpenSQLConnection. Apparently due to some problem with Java(?). I tried to reinstall JRE 8, but no change.

DatabaseExplorer[] gives "Error: JDBC::error" on the connect page.

Any idea how to approach this, what to try?

[image: Output from failed OpenSQLConnection]

Comment: Is this a JDBC driver you set up yourself or one that came packaged with MMA? I don't know the details exactly, but I think it's possible that DatabaseLink has it's own JRE packaged with MMA, so the JRE you have installed may not be picked up.

Comment: I am using similar code on version 12.1.  I'll upgrade one of my machines to 12.3 and see if it still works.

Comment: I updated to 12.3 and now my SQL code does not work on that computer. I even tried the suggestion from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41431/opensqlconnection-error?rq=1 but it didn't help.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit It’s the included driver. When my code didn’t work, I tried installing JRE 8,  with no change in result. Could the driver be faulty, cf Rudy Potter”s experience?

Comment: I just tried to revert to MMA 12.2 and here I have no problem with my code above! Any suggestions where to look for differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the following from Wolfram and it worked for me:

As a workaround, please try the following:

1. Download Microsoft mssql jdbc driver zip fie from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#download
2. Unzip the driver
3. Copy mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar to `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "DatabaseLink", "Java"}]`

Then connect to mssql database as follows:

```
In[1]:= Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
In[2]:= con4 = OpenSQLConnection[ JDBC["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "jdbc:sqlserver://" <> "host" ], "Catalog" ->"dbname", "Username" ->"username", "Password" ->"password" ]
```

Comment: Forgot to mark this as "solved", i.e. the workaround worked. The basic issue was resolved in version 13.