# Who broke the JDBC?

Tags: sql, jdbc

For the last 10 years or so, I have been accessing the tables of a PostgreSQL database successfully. Suddenly, having upgraded to Version 13.0, I get error messages in the simplest of queries, such as listing the columns of a table. (The connection itself is established without error.)

[image]

Mind you, this is not new code I wrote, this is code that's been functioning since forever. Nothing has happened to the database as I can query it successfully with the Python code I have also had since forever.

I am thinking this is as "updated" JDBC driver issue. Does anyone know how to undo this "improvement" without reverting to an older version of Mathematica?

Comment: What version information do you get from `JDBCDrivers[] `? You can install and resister the version you know works and use it explicitly in your connection.

Comment: JDBCDrivers[] gives me, among others, JDBCDriver["Name" -> "PostgreSQL", 
 "Driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver", 
 "Protocol" -> "jdbc:postgresql://", "Version" -> 3.1, 
 "Description" -> 
  "PostgreSQL using PostgreSQL JDBC Driver - Version 42.1.4.", 
 "Location" -> 
  "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/\
DatabaseLink/DatabaseResources/postgresql.m"]

Comment: If that version is not working then download and install the version you need (does not need to be in a Mma install subdirectory). Register it in Mma (see the guide) and they used that registered name in your connections.

Comment: Similar problem here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253551/opensqlconnection-fails-due-to-some-java-problem#comment633794_253551 with solution. But that issue was supposedly fixed in 13. :(